# Подключение одного проекта к другому xcode 5 ios

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Когда просто перетаскиваю один проект в другой, то xcode не находит хидеры подключенного проекта. Искал, но нигде ничего нету подобного. Видел, что проект можно скомпилировать в библиотеку и подключить в другой, но что-то неполючается никак.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас название Заголовка вопроса и постановка вопроса отличаются. Я так понял что Вам нужно смержить/скомбинировать проект.

1. [Two Xcode Projects and 1 App](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45800-two-xcode-projects-and-1-app.html)
2. [How to combine two projects in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504214/how-to-combine-two-projects-in-xcode)